# Can i Make Labels Clickable in tkinter and get the Value of label clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like user to click on the number's and then the number should change color and i shall be able to capture on what label user has clicked, this form then shall be saved in Text and PDF format..Thanks a mil in advance for any help

from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import  messagebox

```
class Proj_pres:
    """Defininf clickable labels in frame"""
    #def fr_lb(self):

    def __init__(self,master):

        master.title(" Feedback Form")
        #master.resizable(False,False)

        self.frame_header = ttk.Frame(master, borderwidth = 5, relief ='ridge').grid(sticky = NE)
        #self.frame_header.pack()

        ttk.Label(self.frame_header, text = " For recording feedback on Autumn(inerm) project presentations",
                         font=('Arial',16,'bold')).grid(row = 0, column = 0,sticky = NW)

        """Defining new frame"""
        self.frame_content = ttk.Frame(master,borderwidth = 5)
        self.frame_content.grid(row = 2, column = 0,columnspan = 3, sticky = NW)


        """Adding check buttons for Studio 1 and Studio 2"""
        self.chkb1 = IntVar()
        self.b1 = ttk.Checkbutton(self.frame_content, text = "UC1Studio1", variable = self.chkb1).grid(row =0,column = 0)

        self.chkb2 = IntVar()
        self.b2 = ttk.Checkbutton(self.frame_content, text = "UC2Studio2", variable = self.chkb2).grid(row = 0, column = 8,columnspan = 2,stick=W)

        """Adding Labels for Team and Reviewer"""

        ttk. Label(self.frame_content, text = "Team Name").grid(row =4, column = 0,sticky = W)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_content, text = "Reviewer").grid(row = 4,column = 7, sticky = E)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_content).grid(row=2, column=0)


        """Adding Entry Boxes for team name and reviewer"""
        ttk.Entry(self.frame_content).grid( row = 4, column = 1,columnspan = 4,sticky = W)
        ttk.Entry(self.frame_content).grid( row = 4, column = 8,columnspan = 2, sticky = E)

        """Adding Label and frame for grading info"""
        self.frame_info = ttk.Frame(master,borderwidth = 5, relief = 'solid')
        self.frame_info.grid(row = 3, column = 0,sticky = NW)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_info).grid(row =5,column = 0)

        ttk.Label(self.frame_info, text ="Please use the feeedback scale for each of the following criterion, "
                                            "where 5 = excellent and 1 = poor").grid(row = 7, column = 0,sticky = W)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_info).grid(row = 6, column =0)

        ttk.Label(self.frame_info,text = "OVERVIEW OF PROJECT").grid(row = 8, column = 0, sticky = NW)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_info, text = "  5: Well Structured,4: Clear aim, 3:Understandable project "
                                          "view").grid(row = 9, column = 0, sticky = NW)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_info, text="  2: Absent,1: Confused "
                                        "view").grid(row=9, column=5, sticky=NW)

        #ttk.Label(self.frame_info, text="  should come here").grid(row=9, column=1, sticky=NW)

        """Adding frame in column 2 for clickable Labels"""
        self.frame_clk=ttk.Frame(self.frame_info, borderwidth= 5, relief ='solid')
        self.frame_clk.grid(row = 9,column = 2,columnspan = 3,sticky = NW)


        self.f1_l5 = StringVar()

        l5 = ttk.Label(self.frame_clk,text = "  5  " ,
                       background = 'white',borderwidth=5,relief= 'ridge',font =('Helvetica',12,'bold'))
        #,textvariable = self.f1_l5
        l5.grid(row=0,column =1,columnspan =2 )
        f1_l4= ttk.Label(self.frame_clk, text="  4  ",background = 'white',borderwidth=5,relief= 'ridge', font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
        f1_l4.grid(row =0 , column = 3)
        f1_l3 = ttk.Label(self.frame_clk, text="  3  ",background = 'white',borderwidth=5,relief= 'ridge', font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
        f1_l3.grid(row=0, column=4)
        f1_l2 = ttk.Label(self.frame_clk, text="  2  ",background = 'white',borderwidth=5,relief= 'ridge', font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
        f1_l2.grid(row=0, column=5)
        f1_l1 = ttk.Label(self.frame_clk, text="  1  ",background = 'white', borderwidth=5,relief= 'ridge',font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
        f1_l1.grid(row=0, column=6)





        #elf.frame_content.pack()
def main():
    root = Tk()
    proj_pres = Proj_pres(root)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```

Comment: read up on how to use the `bind` method.

Comment: i got the bind method working but am still unable to change the color of Label on click

Answer (score 2):

```
    def clickFunction(event): #event is argument with info about event that triggered the function
        global selectedNumber #make the number visible throughout the program, don't need this if you'll just pass it as argument to function
        event.widget.config(background = "green") #event.widget is reference to widget that was clicked on and triggered the function 
        selectedNumber = 7 - event.widget.grid_info()["column"] #grid info is dictionary with info about widget's grid relative to widget, more at http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid-methods.html
        if(selectedNumber > 5): selectedNumber = 5 
        print(selectedNumber)
        ''' if someday you won't use grid, but will use list to store Labels, this is a way to get Label's position
        selectedNumber = myLabels.index(event.widget)
        '''
    l5.bind("<Button-1>", clickFunction)
    f1_l4.bind("<Button-1>", clickFunction)
    f1_l3.bind("<Button-1>", clickFunction)
    f1_l2.bind("<Button-1>", clickFunction)
    f1_l1.bind("<Button-1>", clickFunction)

    ''' Alternative way for making lots of similar widgets, not to mention extending Label class
    myLabels = [] #create List to make code more compact and to be able to use loops
    for i in range(5, 0, -1):
        myLabels.append(ttk.Label(self.frame_clk, text="  " + str(i) + "  ",background = 'white',borderwidth=5,relief= 'ridge', font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
        myLabels.bind("<Button-1>", clickFunction)
        myLabels[i].grid(row =0 , column = 6 - i)
    '''
```

Here is code you can add below "f1_l1.grid(row=0, column=6)" line (around ln 77). But I think you might need RadioButton for that purpose since it automatically unmarks other options and supports IntVar. More about events: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/events.html This webpage has excellent (but a bit outdated) documentation.

Btw, there is one quick fix you might want to apply when making programs for yourself. In Python you can add fields to classes and their instances outside their definition. E.g. in your code, you cold have written f1_l1.myNumber = 1 after "creating" it and in clickFunction instead of grid_info() use selectedNumber = event.widget.myNumber. It'd do the thing, but don't tell them I taught you that ;) since it isn't considered good practice adding fields that way.

If you have any more questions feel free to ask.

Comment: I lost a tab in the first row while copying. Thanks for pointing that out. Now it's ready to be  copy - pasted directly into main code.

Comment: Hi @noob Thanks a mil for your input it definitely helps me, also i  like your advice, will take up that. Thanks a mil for helping :) i might need your help again as i still have to figure our a way to save the form as text and Pdf :)

Comment: but you recommend adding radio buttons instead of labels? my whole point was it will look neat this way.. i'm new to python, my prev experience is all in VB and asp's :)

Comment: radio buttons are good because they already work the way you'd like those labels to work so you don't need additional code to cover their funcionality, but they indeed look different, even when indicatoron option is set to False. It's up to you to choose whether you want to code unselecting other labels when another label is pressed or you want to adjust radiobuttons' appearance. I don't have much experience with exporting tkinter form to pdf and pdf in Python in general, but writing data to txt file shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: how can I get the text of the label that is clicked